# How to launch android applications from another application

Tags: android

I want to launch any one of the existing android applications (contacts, call dialer, etc.)
from my app upon on click of a button.

All that I know is to get the Intent of the particular app and start the activity. But I don't  know how to set the class path for the intent for contacts.

Am I following the correct solution? What is the way to launch another application?

Answer (score 5):

You don't really call another application - you generate the intent and then wait for someone to pick it up. Are you referring to Contact's app URL as "class path"? If so here's [Contacts.Intents helper class reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.Intents.html) that you can use to create Contacts intents

Here's a short example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Contacts.Intents.SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT);
```

Comment: Actually i wan to dial a number on click on button.
I tried with this code :
Intent dialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:666444666"));

startActivity(dialIntent);

But this is not working.Do you have any idea how do i proceed with this.

Comment: One thing that you should check is to add permission to your manifest file. Do you have any sort of error generated? What's in the log when you execute that line of code?

Comment: The code which is workin to dial a number is

Intent dialIntent = new Intent( "android.intent.action.DIAL",Uri.parse("tel:666444666"));
          startActivity(dialIntent);

users Permission is manifest file:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>


This perfectly working....

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: This is a simple code rite ? . the developer can get the solution from this code. anyway.. i will explain.. You have to provide the package name of the application which u have to run from another application.