# Accessing Android Inbox/Messaging from Activity?

Tags: android, messaging, android-ndk, inbox

Is it possible to open up the default Android Messaging activity from inside an activity you write yourself?  Like for example:  I press a "Mail" button inside my program, and it opens the Android Messaging app just like as if I was to press the Messaging icon on the main screen.

I did something similar to this with the Contacts activity, but only the contact list comes up, no extra functionality like Adding/Modifying/Deleting, etc.

Any ideas?

edit:  I found this way to open the "Compose New Message" Activity, I just need to back it up a step.  Does anyone know the correct MIME type instead of this one?

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms"); 
m_activity.startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Answer (score 3):

This starts the messaging app from another app:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.mms","com.android.mms.ui.ConversationList"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Just put it inside a button listener or whatever user input you want to open it from.

Enjoy :-)

Comment: Sweet thanks, is there a list of these so I could check for other apps to run?  Like the Contacts activity, etc.  Thanks again!

Comment: If you run logcat and start the program you want to start from your own app, you can see what intent the launcher runs to start the app.

Comment: the package specified on the first parameter of ComponentName constructor shouldn't be "com.android.mms.ui"?

Comment: According to logcat on the emulator it doesnt want the ui
"Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.mms/.ui.ConversationList }"
this code is also what works for me :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please help me to understand how to open a particular SMS? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18802365/how-to-make-screenshot-with-sms-received

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the messaging app to view messages and not for sending a message, this should do the job:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.messaging");
startActivity(intent);
```