# Go to Inbox in Android

Tags: android

I had written an simple program in android to show an notification..By click on notification msg i have to go to inbox. I am using the following code.

```
Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"));
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(SimpleNotification.this, 0, 
                    notifyIntent, android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

I am able to recieve notification but by clicking on notification i am not able to go to inbox..

Please any help..thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing Android Inbox/Messaging from Activity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260471/accessing-android-inbox-messaging-from-activity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260471), the following will launch the messaging app.  However, this makes use of undocumented APIs which are not part of the Android core.  Developers should not use the `com.android.mms` application as it is not guaranteed to work in future versions or on all devices.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
intent.setComponent(
    new ComponentName("com.android.mms","com.android.mms.ui.ConversationList"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This will not work on some devices and may not work in future versions of Android. Neither the `com.android.mms` application nor the `content://sms/inbox` content provider should be used by developers, as neither are part of the operating system.