# How to create a new Intent for another app's broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcast, broadcastreceiver

In the examples, they create Intent as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
```

But suppose my AlarmReceiver class is in another app, how do I create this intent?

I've tried with

```
new Intent("com.app.AlarmReceiver")
```

but nothing happens.. It was not called..

Any idea?

--*Broadcast definition added using the manifest editor on Eclipse:*

```
<receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
</application>
```

--
Related:
[How do I start my app from my other app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259912/how-do-i-start-my-app-from-my-other-app/3259975#3259975) (but this same code is not working for broadcasts..)

Comment: How is the broadcast defined in the XML?

Comment: I think you have to define it with the complete name 'com.app.AlarmReceiver' and inside the activity.

Comment: @Cristian C. tried inside and outside with the full name (calling the full name either), but still nothing happens..

Comment: @Tom I had a dejavu. I think I already answered that question to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259912/how-do-i-start-my-app-from-my-other-app/3259975#3259975

Comment: @Cristian C. Actually that was a call to a Activity, unfortunately the same code is not working for broadcast..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But my suppose my AlarmReceiver class
>   is in another app, how do I create
>   this intent?

If *you* wrote the other app, add an `<intent-filter>` with a custom action string to the other app's `<receiver>` element, then use an `Intent` with that action string.

If you did not write the other app, ask whoever wrote it what the `Intent` should look like.

Comment: I've written it, and I already add to it: <receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
But it still not working..

Comment: Oh god.. I had forgotten the intent-filter.. Actually, I was writing it in the name attribute.. XD Thanks!